# Создание дочерних форм

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать так, чтобы при создании дочерней формы не создавалась вложенность на панели задач.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы, небось, забыли указать `Owner`'а?

Comment: @murash, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

В конструкторе формы добавьте `this.ShowInTaskbar = false;`.